# xml parsing with simple shell scripting

Tags: xml, shell

can some one please help me on getting xml data into shell scripting

here is my requirement.

I need to print CHILD value along with attribute value of CHILD and parent if the CHILD value is greater than 100

here is my data

```
<mydata>
    <parent detail="school1">
        <CHILD attribute="0">0</CHILD>
        <CHILD attribute="1">1932</CHILD>
        <CHILD attribute="2">0</CHILD>
        <CHILD attribute="3">500</CHILD>
        <CHILD attribute="4">0</CHILD>
        <CHILD attribute="5">0</CHILD>
        <CHILD attribute="6">7819</CHILD>
        <CHILD attribute="7">0</CHILD>
        <CHILD attribute="8">299</CHILD>
        <CHILD attribute="9">0</CHILD>
    </parent>
    <parent detail="school2">
        <CHILD attribute="0">1</CHILD>
        <CHILD attribute="1">7000</CHILD>
        <CHILD attribute="2">0</CHILD>
        <CHILD attribute="3">0</CHILD>
        <CHILD attribute="4">600</CHILD>
        <CHILD attribute="5">0</CHILD>
        <CHILD attribute="6">11674</CHILD>
        <CHILD attribute="7">0</CHILD>
        <CHILD attribute="8">489</CHILD>
        <CHILD attribute="9">0</CHILD>
    </parent>
</mydata>
```

my external file values are like this
childvalue_limits.txt file

```
attribute0=100
attribute1=60
attribute3=80
attribute4=90
attribute5=100
attribute6=90
attribute7=50
attribute8=80
attribute9=70
```

I need to pass this file as argument to script and to take these values dynamically into the condition..

current code

```
sed 's|><|>\n<|g' $WORKING_PATH/xml_detail.log | awk -F'"|<|>' '/parent detail/{p=$3} /CHILD attribute/{att=$3;val=$5;if(val>100)print  "child value on " p, "attribute "att,"is at value: "val ,"\n"}'
```

current output

```
child value on school2 attribute 1 is at value 1000
child value on school2 attribute 4 is at value 600
.....
.....
```

required output should be like this

```
child value on school2 attribute 1 is at value 1000 and threshold is 60
child value on school2 attribute 4 is at value 600 and threshold is 90
.....
.....
```

please note: threshold value is the dynamic value passed to if condition through a separate file called childvalue_limits.txt

Comment: Your question is ambiguous. Do you mean you need the child value and attribute and parent for all children whose value exceeeds 100. or do you mean you need child value and attribute, and where the child value exceeeds 100 you need the parent as well? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Show an example output along with what you have done so far.

Comment: If you want to parse XML, use an XML parser (which of course can be run within a shell script). Using awk or any other regular expression based program will use a regular grammar, whereas XML is context-free and can therefore by definition not be correctly parsed by regex.

Answer (score 1):

You can not (correctly) parse XML using regular expression. XML is a context-free language, which is more expressive than a grammar based on regular expressions. See the Chomsky hierarchy for details. That is also the reason why you run into troubles with newlines when using regular expressions.

Hence, it is better (and easier and more stable) to use a proper XML parser. As I am most familiar with [BaseX](http://basex.org) (full disclousure: I am also associated with the project) I will use it.

When using the zip version, you can simple run the file `bin/basex`. The following XPath 3.0 expression should give you the correct output, simply concatenating the different values:

```
for $c in /mydata/parent/CHILD[. > 100] return $c/parent::parent/@detail || " " || $c/@attribute || " " || $c/data() || "&#10;"
```

Assuming your xml file is named `mydata.xml` you can execute this XPath simply by issueing the following command (i.e. this can be done in your shell script):

```
basex -i mydata.xml -q 'for $c in /mydata/parent/CHILD[. > 100] return $c/parent::parent/@detail || " " || $c/@attribute || " " || $c/data() || "&#10;"'
```

Comment: @MarkSetchell You are very welcome - Welcome to the magical and mysterious journey that is XPath/XQuery processing ;-) Yes, we do have a simply homebrew install; for all debian (or debian-derived) users it should also be in the central repository (although slightly outdated, if I remember correctly).

Comment: +1 Excellent - that works nicely, thank you. For any OSX Mac users out there, I installed `basex` very simply with `brew install basex`.

Comment: Fixed a typo... and re-commented.

Answer (score 0):

**EDITED AGAIN**

Ok, I have changed the code to read a file of input limits. It looks complicated but it is is not - you can remove all the lines that have the word "DEBUG" in them if you want to. The `#` is the start of a comment.

```
#!/bin/bash

awk -F'"|<|>' '
   FNR==NR           {
                       split($0,f,"=");  # Split line on "=" sign into array f[]
                       gsub(/[[:alpha:]]/,"",f[1]); # Remove non-digits
                       limits[f[1]]=f[2]; # Save for comparison later
                       print "DEBUG: limits[",f[1],"]=",f[2];
                       next
                     }
   /parent detail/   {
                       p=$3
                       print "DEBUG: parent detail=",p;
                     }
   /CHILD attribute/ {
                       att=$3;val=$5;
                       print "DEBUG: att=",att,",val=",val; 
                       if(val>limits[att])print p,att,val,limits[att]
                     }
   ' limits.txt xml
```

You will see at the end of the script that it reads in BOTH your files - `limits.txt` and `xml`. In the script, the block in curly braces that starts `FNR==NR` means that the following code only applies to reading and parsing `limits.txt`.

If you want to see the output without `DEBUG` messages, just run

```
./script | grep -v DEBUG
```

**EDITED**

Your code works fine for me with your revised data. Here is my output:

```
node2 1 1932
node2 6 7819
node1 1 1924
node1 6 11674
```

I assume you mean you want to avoid XML parsers and just use standard tools like `awk` and `sed` to achieve this, so I'll go with `awk`

```
awk -F'"|<|>' '/parent detail/{p=$3} /CHILD attribute/{att=$3;val=$5;if(val>100)print p,att,val}' xml
```

**Output:**

```
school1 1 1932
school1 3 500
school1 6 7819
school1 8 299
school2 1 7000
school2 4 600
school2 6 11674
school2 8 489
```

So, it sets the separator to any of `"`, `<` or `>`. Then, when it sees lines with the words "parent detail" it saves the value in `p`. When it sees lines with the words `CHILD attribute` it extracts the attribute and value. If the value is over 100, it prints the parent, attribute and value.

It assumes your XML is in a file called `xml`.

Comment: thanks Mark

but the above code not working while changing values in the xml data.

awk -F'"|<|>' '/ALLQUEUEDEPTHS server/{p=$3} /QUEUE_DEPTH queue/{att=$3;val=$5;if(val>100)print p,att,val}' ./myfile.xml

Comment: Can you click `edit` underneath your question and paste in an XML file that my code doesn't work for please?

Comment: it doesn't allow me to paste xml file
is there any way to send xml data to you ?

Comment: Put it in the same way as you put the original data in.

Comment: I have updated my answer - are you using `GNU awk`, or can you try using it - installed as `gawk` maybe?

Comment: it works now, THANKS....its just a formatting error, code works only when the data in the file should be in xml tree structure, if its like a plain text, it is not working

Comment: Mark, is there any way to apply this code to the xml data that is not in xml tree structure ? i.e., continuous tags without linebreaks

Comment: Mmmm... you could use `perl` to find all occurences of greater than followed by a space (`> `) and replace witha new line to make the file have each tag on a new line so that the `awk` works... `perl -pe 's/>\s/\n/g'  xml | awk '{...}'`

Comment: Actually, you can do that more easily in `awk`, just change your `awk` to this `awk -F'"|<|>' 'BEGIN{RS="> "} /ALLQUEUEDEPTH....`

Comment: it works fine with sed 's|><|>\n<|g' xml for inserting line breaks

Comment: If that works, then this is an easier way of doing the same thing... `awk -F'"|<|>' 'BEGIN{RS="><"} /ALLQUEUEDEPTH....`

Comment: I strongly advise against using regex for "parsing" XML, as it is simply not possible (XML is a context-free language). If anything changes in the XML (i.e. a line-break, so not even a real change) the regex will become incorrect. Use an XML parser!

Comment: @dirkk I agree that an XML parser is the way to go, but the OP specifically asks for a simple shell scripted implementation.

Comment: Well, you can also call an XMP parser from a shell script. After all, `awk` and `sed` are also simply programs which are called from within the shell script. And even this aside, if the OP wants something unreasonable I would still argue to simply advise against that (and possibly short the correct/better way) instead of giving an incorrect reply. I know, I know - regex parsing works in the case. But I guarantee it, there comes nothing but trouble from this as small changes in the XML can break the whole application flow.

Comment: @dirkk I'm all ears if you want to provide an answer showing the proper way to do it... :-)

Comment: Well, normally I am just here to complain and nag about other peoples answers.... but as you asked so nicely I added an answer ;)

Comment: @MarkSetchell, is there any way to add condition value dynamically ?? sed 's|><|>\n<|g' $WORKING_PATH/xml_detail.log | awk -F'"|<|>' '/ALLQUEUEDEPTHS server/{p=$3} /QUEUE_DEPTH queue/{att=$3;val=$5;if(val>100)print p,val ,"\n"}' 
in the above code I need to pass condition value from external file to each child attribute –

*****so in the above condition if (val>100), I need to pass 100 as dynamically for each child attribute****

can you please help me with that ??

Comment: You can pass a value (i.e. variable) into `awk` like this, by adding `-v variable=37`, so if you want to test values less than 37 and 37 is in a shell variable called `limit`, you can do `awk -v val=$limit '{if(x<val)...}'`

Comment: @MarkSetchell, I have edited my question above, can you please check and suggest??

my current code
sed 's|><|>\n<|g' $WORKING_PATH/xml_detail.log | awk -F'"|<|>' '/ALLQUEUEDEPTHS server/{p=$3} /QUEUE_DEPTH queue/{att=$3;val=$5;if(val>100)print p,val ,"\n"}'

Comment: It is too hard to understand code in Comment fields, please click `edit` under your question and describe in there what I need to do with the new list of values. Thanks.

Comment: @MarkSetchell, edited question as requested... please check and suggst..thanks

Comment: @MarkSetchell, please let me know  if were not able to understand my requirement, I can eloborate..please suggest me the solution as I am a new bee to this scripting language...

Comment: @Praveen I think it should work nicely for you now - note that you missed `attribute2` in your `limits.txt` file.